# ViewComponent Navigation Buttons Don't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using .NET Core MVC. The navigation links I am trying to create don't seem to work correctly. I have the following model:

```
public class Model
    {
        public long ModelID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SolverType { get; set; } 
        public string ProgramType { get; set; } 

    }
```

This ViewModel passed is:

```
public class ModelsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public string CurrentProgramType { get; set; }
    }
```

The View is:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

    <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary"asp-action="Index"
       asp-controller="Home" asp-route-type="">
        Home
    </a>
    //THESE DON'T LINK APPROPRIATELY TO THE CONTROLLER
    @foreach (string type in Model)
    {
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary"
           asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home"
           asp-route-type="@type"
           asp-route-modelPage="1">
            @type
        </a>
    }
```

The Home controller action is:

```
 public ViewResult Index(string type, int modelPage = 1)
            => View(new ModelsListViewModel
            {
                Models = repository.Models
                    .Where(m => type == null || m.ProgramType == type)
                    .OrderBy(m => m.ModelID)
                    .Skip((modelPage - 1) * PageSize)
                    .Take(PageSize),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = modelPage,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = type == null ?
                        repository.Models.Count() :
                        repository.Models.Where(e =>
                            e.ProgramType == type).Count()
                },
                CurrentProgramType = type
            });
```

When the page renders the view component buttons are displayed, but the links do not work or display when hovered over. They don't seem to call any action within the controller.

EDIT: Here is the routing defined in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("typepage",
                    "{type}/Page{modelPage:int}",
                    new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("page", "Page{modelPage:int}",
                    new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", modelPage = 1 });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("type", "{type}",
                    new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", modelPage = 1 });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("pagination",
                    "Models/Page{modelPage}",
                    new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index", modelPage = 1 });
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
```

EDIT2: This is the ViewComponent that renders the buttons:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View(repository.Models
                .Select(x => x.ProgramType)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x)); ;
        }
```

EDIT3:
Here is the `PageingInfo` class to address a comment left:

```
 public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; } 
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage);
    }
```

Comment: Are these route is defined route table in `Startup.cs` file? Is the action of this controller directly routable? Asp tag helpers for routing are using route table to generate the URL back from the peaces You have them. The default route only defines one optional parameter. Try to either make method with one int param to test or add a route with two params to the route template. Post the value of `href` attribute which is generated.

Comment: @Eatos I've added the routing from my Startup.cs file to the post. I'm not seeing any href generated

Comment: @coolhand I'm trying to recreate in an example .net core mvc project. I'm getting an error for "PagingInfo" type in ModelsListViewModel. Do you have a nuget package installed for this or do you have a class for this in your project ?

Comment: @AntiqTech `PagingInfo` is a separate class used to create pagination links, stored with my ViewModels folder. I've edited my post to add that class

Comment: This is my example data: https://imgur.com/a/0KJrfBo  . I didn't use viewcomponent, instead I have made changes to view code : @model ModelsListViewModel   ,  foreach (string type in Model.Models
                .Select(x => x.ProgramType)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x))   .  After these changes, I got this output :  https://imgur.com/a/3U8ZT3t  I can see the link as seen at the bottom when hover over it. Can you check the screenshot to see if this is of  any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the way you are generating the link's URL. The URL generated is something like `/home/index/my-type/1` where `my-type` is an assumed value from the model.

Since your mappings in the server expect the page prefixed with the word `Page` you will never hit a matching route. You need to change the code creating the link to something like:

```
<!-- 
Check modelPage value is now "Page1". Here is the change which generates the URL like
"/home/index/my-type/Page1" as you mapped server side.
-->
<a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary"
           asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home"
           asp-route-type="@type"
           asp-route-modelPage="Page1">
            @type
        </a>
```

Also, make sure to import the tag helpers

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: To extend your example, it's set up so that "/home/index/?modelPage=2" and "home/index/Page2" both return the same view. The issue is that, as written in my original post, no href appears to be generated by the buttons

Comment: The problem is that ASP.NET does not find a route that matches the parameter value for "modelPage" parameter since you are not prefixing with "Page" string. Since no route mathes the single digit "1" no URL is generated since ASP.NET does not know what to do.

Comment: It was actually just a spelling error in my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. Thank you for helping me track it down.